# Basic functionality of RunThrough

Tags: external-calls

The documentation for `RunThrough["command",expr]` says that it executes an external command and returns the result. Does that mean it executes it as if on the command line? Why does this not return the string "blah" (or maybe "blah\r\n")?

```
RunThrough["echo","blah"]
```

(I'm on Windows.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. I still think `echo` writes to Window's equivalent of stdout.

Comment: Given the way `RunThrough` works, the expression that will give you the behavior you expect is `RunThrough["cat", "blah"]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That

```
RunThrough["echo", "blah"]
```

doesn't work appears strange because on my system, OS X, which means the terminal command line is talking to Free BSD Unix, `man echo` gives

> echo -- write arguments to the standard output

Further, both

```
RunThrough["cat", "blah"]
```

and

```
RunThrough["echo blah", ""]
```

work.

#### Update

It turns out the operative phrase in my quote from the Unix `man` page is "write arguments". That is, `echo` does not accept input from standard input. It only writes the arguments that follow the token `echo` on the command line to standard output. The documentation for `RunThrough` says the second argument is passed to the OS command mentioned in the first argument by standard input. I assume this means pipped in.

This explains the behavior encountered by the OP and why `RunThrough["echo blah", ""]` works.

Comment: `RunThrough["echo blah", ""]` works on Windows too. +1 and disregard my earlier comments.  (I'll delete them later after people have had ample chance to see and laugh at them. :o)

Comment: So it was the *input* channel rather than the output channel that was the problem.  Thanks for tracking that down.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Yes